# Kubernetes ingress custom JWT authentication cache key

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, ingress-nginx

We are leveraging Kubernetes ingress with external service [JWT authentication](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#external-authentication) using `auth-url` as a part of the ingress.

Now we want to use the `auth-cache-key` annotation to control the caching of JWT token.  At current our external auth service just respond with `200`/`401` by looking at the token. All our components are backend micro-services with rest api. Incoming request may not be the UI request. How do we fill in the `auth-cache-key' for a JWT token coming in.

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://auth-service/validate
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: "authorization"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-cache-key: '$remote_user$http_authorization'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-cache-duration: '1m'
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
```

Looking at the example, `$remote_user$http_authorization` is specified as an example in K8s documentation. However not sure if `$remote_user` will be set in our case. Because this is not external basic auth. How do we decide on the auth cache key in case of this?

Not enough example/documentations exists around this.

Comment: Which Kubernetes and NGINX Ingress controller versions are you using?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "Incoming request may not be the UI request. and "How do we decide on the auth cache key in case of this?" What exactly is your issue? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example of your current setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting general answer as no further details and explanation provided.

It's true that there is not so much documentation around, so I decided to dig into [NGINX Ingress source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx).

The value set in annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-cache-key` is a variable `$externalAuth.AuthCacheKey` [in code](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/07e54431ff069a5452a1f68ca3dbb98da0e0f35b/rootfs/etc/nginx/template/nginx.tmpl#L986):

```
{{ if $externalAuth.AuthCacheKey }}
set $tmp_cache_key '{{ $server.Hostname }}{{ $authPath }}{{ $externalAuth.AuthCacheKey }}';
set $cache_key '';
```

As can see, `$externalAuth.AuthCacheKey` is used by variable `$tmp_cache_key`, which is encoded to `base64` format and set as variable `$cache_key` using [lua NGINX module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#name):

```
rewrite_by_lua_block {
    ngx.var.cache_key = ngx.encode_base64(ngx.sha1_bin(ngx.var.tmp_cache_key))
}
```

Then `$cache_key` is used to set [variable `$proxy_cache_key` which defines a key for caching](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_key):

```
proxy_cache_key "$cache_key";
```

Based on the above code, we can assume that we can use any [NGINX variable](https://www.javatpoint.com/nginx-variables) to set `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-cache-key` annotation. Please note that some variables are only available if the [corresponding module is loaded](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html).

Example - I set following `auth-cache-key` annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-cache-key: '$proxy_host$request_uri'
```

Then, on the NGINX Ingress controller pod, in the file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` there is following line:

```
set $tmp_cache_key '{my-host}/_external-auth-Lw-Prefix$proxy_host$request_uri';
```

If you will set `auth-cache-key` annotation to nonexistent NGINX variable, the NGINX will throw following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown "nonexistent_variable" variable
```

It's up to you which variables you need.

Please check also following articles and topics:

- [A Guide to Caching with NGINX and NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/)
- [external auth provider results in a *lot* of external auth requests](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2862)